# Ionic application run from another location gives error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application. I created with all commands added few plugins etc. It builds and runs properly for android as well as ios. I have checked-in into SVN. Now if I checkout same application to some other location or to some other PC and try to build or run(ionic run android) then it is giving me error.
'You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project'

Please help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to go through the whole process of installing the Android SDK etc, if you haven't.  you also may need to run `cordova platform update android` or one of the other solutions here:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/282

Comment: Yes it seems we have to run  D:\> cordova platform remove android .And.    

cordova platform add android  To make it runnable. Just checkout wont work.